# C++ pure virtual function inheritance (same signature)

Tags: c++, inheritance, method-signature

Why is this not compiling?
error C2660: 'Concrete::WriteLine' : function does not take 1 arguments
I know if i add the Line:
//using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
it works, but i dont understand why.

```
#include "iostream" 

class AbstractBase
{
public:
   virtual void WriteLine() = 0;
   virtual void WriteLine( int i )
   {
      std::cout<<"AbstractBase"<<std::endl;
   }
};

class Concrete : public AbstractBase
{
public:
   //using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
   virtual void WriteLine()
   {
      std::cout<<"Concrete Sub Class"<<std::endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Concrete ff;
   ff.WriteLine();
   ff.WriteLine(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain me what happens here.
Thanx

---

Does anyone knows if this behavior is a defined behavior from the C++ standart. 
Is it mentioned in the C++ standart?
Or is it just a kind of compiler behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you declare a function:

```
void WriteLine()
```

in derived class it ***hides*** all the base class functions with the same name.
The above function which takes no parameters hides the function with same name and taking one parameter, Since compiler cannot find a function with one parameter it reports a error.

The line:

```
using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
```

enables(*brings in scope*) all the hidden names from the Base class in your derived class and hence the function taking one parameter is available.

Good Read:
[What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9)

Answer (score 2):

**Method hiding** happens. The other function in the base class is hidden by the function with the same name, although it has a different signature.

To solve this, you can use a `using` directive:

```
using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
```

in the derived class:

```
class Concrete : public AbstractBase
{
public:
   using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
   //using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
   virtual void WriteLine()
   {
      std::cout<<"Concrete Sub Class"<<std::endl;
   }
};
```

Comment: What you have is an ***using namespace declaration*** and not ***using namespace directive***, both are not the same.

Comment: @Als: Just a _using declaration_. There are no namespaces involved.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Erm..Yes, True. I went for the keywords because searching those would yield the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a function in a derived class hides all functions with the same name in the base class - they are not considered as potential overloads of the derived class functions.

Adding the `using` declaration brings the hidden functions back into the scope of the derived class, and they are considered as potential overloads along with the derived class functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Concrete::WriteLine` is hiding all `AbstractBase::WriteLines`. You can add

```
using AbstractBase::WriteLine;
```

to your derived class.